# Windows 7: how to select all files of a certain type located in my desktop?

Tags: windows-7

I wan't to select all .mp3 files from my desktop with one click, or through a shortcut/software.

Is there a way to do this?

If not', I would be glad if you gave me some directions onto how to write such script.

Comment: Open Explorer and navigate to your desktop > search .mp3 or arrange by type?

Comment: Confine your search to desktop and *.mp3 files and delete all the files that appear in the search result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes there is a very simple way. Open Desktop in Explorer (Open Computer then on the left side under Favorites click on Desktop or click the arrow pointing to the right beside the computer icon in the address bar then select Desktop.)

> Right click, then Group by>item type

Click on the >MP3 file type expansion bar and it will select all the .mp3 files listed and then shift-del (shortcut for permanent deletion [it doesn't go to the recycle]) or right-click and delete.

That's the best way of deleting all your mp3 files from your desktop or any other files with the same extensions.

My advice, first to myself then to all other lazy fellows out there, be active!

I hope that helps

Comment: I'm amazed. Won't ever clean my desktop icon by icon again.

Answer (score 2):

Type *.* in the search space and it seems to stack all the files/items in Folders by Type as it did in Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0):

In search box, just type it as it is: ".type" without quotes and then click enter.
In this case, just search ".mp3".

Comment: seems more like a comment

Comment: @StupidWolf: It offers an answer to the question, so it's acceptable as an answer. The bigger issue, to me, is that it's effectively reiterating [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15882726/3025856) from eight years ago.